# Typing a class property with an imported constant

Tags: typescript

I have constants I use globally and want to reference in a class. Specifically, I have a class property that I want to type as those constants. For example:

```
export const ALICE = 1;
export const BETTY = 2;
export const CARL = 3;
```

...

```
import {ALICE, BETTY, CARL} from './constants';
import {FooModel} from './foo.model';

export class MyClass {
    public constantsExample: ALICE | BETTY | CARL;
    public modelExample: FooModel;
    public stringExample: string;
}
```

I know I can reference an object as a type, such as `FooModel` above. However, this approach fails as `MyClass` does not recognize `ALICE` or `BETTY` or `CARL`. Is there way to use imported constants as types?

Comment: You will need to show how those constants are defined.

Comment: @Nit I added how the constants are defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what your actual use case is, but your constants look like they would better fit in an [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html). If you need specific values, you can assign those too, but those are completely optional.

```
enum Humans {
    ALICE = 1,
    BETTY, // Automatically = 2 and so on.
    CARL
}
```

If you want, you could also use a [string literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types), but enums are both easier to maintain and to use.

Answer (score 1):

To query the type of variable you can use `typeof` operator:

```
public constantsExample: typeof ALICE | typeof BETTY | typeof CARL;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a classic Constants approach by exporting a class named `Constants` and defining the values there. That way you can mix and match any value type you like.

`Constants.ts`

```
export class Constants {
  public static get ALICE() {
    return "Alice";
  }
  public static get BETTY() {
    return 1;
  }
  public static get API_URL() {
    return "mydomain.com/api/";
  }
}
```

Then import the `Constants` file wherever you want to get a specific value:

`app.component.ts`

```
import { Constants } from '../Constants';

...

let test = `${Constants.ALICE} is my friend`;
```